# Arranging Child elements in stackpanel

Tags: c#, xaml, visual-studio-2012

I have created a Inkcanvas control using seperate class.I have created stackpanel in the following way.I am trying to insert the inkcanvas in stackpanel.in the following way.but the inkcanvas is added outside the window.Please find my error.

XAML Code is

```
<StackPanel  Name="stkm" Background="CadetBlue" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Orientation="Horizontal" Width="1140" Margin="0,107,-1,94" Grid.Column="1">
    <Grid Height="459" Name="grid2" Width="1130">

    </Grid>
</StackPanel>
```

my inkcanvas class code is

```
class mycan : InkCanvas
{
    string name;
    public mycan(string n)
    {
        name = n;
        this.Width =  250;
        this.Height = 200;
        // MouseDown += class1_MouseDown;
        Margin = new Thickness(5, 2, 5, 2);           

        // MouseRightButtonDown += class1_MouseRightButtonDown;     
    }
}
```

Iam adding the stackpanel children in the following way

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    mycan mycanvas1 = new mycan("PA");
    mycan mycanvas2 = new mycan("RA");
    mycan mycanvas3 = new mycan("JA");           
    stkm.Children.Add(mycanvas1);
    stkm.Children.Add(mycanvas2);
    stkm.Children.Add(mycanvas3);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem is that the Grid you've added to the StackPanel in your XAML file almost completely fills the StackPanel - the StackPanel is 1140px wide while the Grid is 1130px wide.

Keep in mind that StackPanels work using a relative layout, meaning that the position of one element depends on the size and position of the previous element. This means that, after the Grid, there are only 10px of StackPanel left for your InkCanvas. If your intent is to use absolute layout, add the canvases to your Grid control instead.

I also concur with Mike Eason's point though. In general it's a best practice to keep as much UI code in XAML as possible. You can use the Visibility property to show/hide the canvases at runtime. This property can be changed via code-behind or, even better, using a databinding.

```
<StackPanel  Name="stkm" Background="CadetBlue" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Orientation="Horizontal" Width="1140" Margin="0,107,-1,94" Grid.Column="1">
    <InkCanvas Name="PA" Width="250" Height="250" Margin="5, 2, 5, 2" Visibility="Visible" />
    <InkCanvas Name="RA" Width="250" Height="250" Margin="5, 2, 5, 2" Visibility="Visible" />
    <InkCanvas Name="JA" Width="250" Height="250" Margin="5, 2, 5, 2" Visibility="Collapsed" />
</StackPanel>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there any particular reason why you need to dynamically add InkCanvas's into your StackPanel?

A far easier method would be to use the following:

```
<StackPanel  Name="stkm" Background="CadetBlue" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Orientation="Horizontal" Width="1140" Margin="0,107,-1,94" Grid.Column="1">
   <Grid Height="459" Name="grid2" Width="1130">
      <InkCanvas Name="PA" Width="250" Height="200" Margin="5,2"/>
      <InkCanvas Name="RA" Width="250" Height="200" Margin="5,2"/>
      <InkCanvas Name="JA" Width="250" Height="200" Margin="5,2"/>
   </Grid>
</StackPanel>
```

Alternatively, if you do need to dynamically generate the InkCanvas's, then you do not really need to inherit from InkCanvas in a new class.

```
InkCanvas mycanvas1 = new InkCanvas()
{
   Name = "PA",
   Width = 250,
   Height = 200,
   Margin = new Thickness(5, 2, 5, 2)
};
```

Comment: Thank You,if more Inkcanvases are needed ,from my method just single line coding is enough class1 mycanvas1=new class1("DA");